# Wordpress .htaccess - Permissions vs Security

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

**Scenario**

I am making a wordpress plugin for my own sites that needs access to the site's main `.htaccess` file.

Via an install script I can modify the `.htaccess` from `644` to `664` which allows my server (apache2) to write to the `.htaccess` directly.

**Question**

What I'm concerned about is the limitation of security. Am I opening myself up to a flurry of potential attacks here? If so what is a better suggestion for making my `.htaccess` writable by wordpress ie. apache?

**EDIT**

The apache2 user is `www-data` on one server but is a different user on a different server depending on the host's settings. I need to be prepared for this.

Comment: WordPress core also writes to .htaccess if it is writable; if it is not, then it notifies the user of what change they need to make manually. You should probably do the same.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm doing that much already. I also include a script for the admin called `permissions.sh` which rewrites the `.htaccess` to 0664. I'm just concerned what risk this may open me up to.

Comment: If the web server is compromised, the attacker can write to writable files.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to the [WordPress stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)? Having `.htaccess` writable in the first place is no doubt the immediate concern (many on WordPress SE recommend locking `.htaccess` down so that it is not editable - which means WP can't update the file). Also, if you are distributing `permissions.sh` - how accessible is this? Is this removed from the server after installation?

Comment: @MrWhite I've been to wordpress stack with this and it was apparent rather quickly that the security aspect wasn't going to be entertained, hence why I came to the security pros w my question. The idea with `permissions.sh` is the that the recursive owner of the WP directory will run it. 1) User downloads git repo for WP plugin 2) user runs `permissions.sh` 3) user installs plugin from WP dashboard. I MAY be able to `chmod` to 664, write to files, then use PHP `chmod` back to 644 but am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question so I'm not sure if it's still relevant, but here's my take on it.

I don't think you're overthinking it as, yes, the file will be writeable. So if anything fishy happens on the server - e.g. an attack which based on changing / creating files on the server, it will be easier for an attacker to compromise the server or adjust certain settings which can be adjusted with .htaccess.

For instance, you can change PHP settings too - like the maximum file upload size and execution times and a host of other configuration values which you don't want changed by an attacker do you? ;)

So my take would be to 440 it and always edit it by hand in a production environment as there it wshould not be required to change it that often anyway (when you're deploying new stuff you change it once to the desired setup and that's it).

In a beta / development environment however, after carefully assessing other security risks, such as what else is on that same server (are there any other sites with sensitive data etc.), you might want to make your developers' life easier by just leaving it at 660 for dev purposes.

Trust that makes sense. 
OP probably is way over this problem by now, but I hope it helps others stumbling upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do to make the file writable by Apache will have the file writable by Apache.

If you only want a limited set of options that Apache can change, you can create a setuid program to make these changes based on some input that is verified by the program. The program should not be setuid to root but to some user that is only the owner of the file.

Comment: That user is `www-data` on one server but is a different user on a different server depending on the host's settings. What can I do in this case? (info also added as an edit to op)

Comment: If it's a file on a shared hosting site, it is unlikely that you will be able to install setuid files. It is enough to have the file readable by apache, so read on group and other is enough. If you can have your program, it should not be setuid to the Apache user, but to a new user that owns only that one file.